# When necessary, how to downgrade npm packages in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, npm

In fresh Laravel 5.8.35

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    }
}
```

Command

```
npm install
```

Command

```
npm run dev
```

*Everything works fine, asset files generated.*

**PROBLEM**

When downgrade bootstrap version as needed.

```
npm i bootstrap@3.4.1
```

Command

```
npm install
```

Command

```
npm run dev
```

Receive Errors :(

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
       ^
      Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
8 │ @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  stdin 8:9  root stylesheet
      in /Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/resources/sass/app.scss (line 8, column 9)
    at /Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:89:7
    at Function.call$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:87203:16)
    at _render_closure1.call$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:76994:12)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:25521:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:25525:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23975:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24271:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3500:88)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24099:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23491:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3256:17)
    at /Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:13326:20
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3279:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23512:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23504:25)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:25521:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:25525:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23975:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24271:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3500:88)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24099:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23491:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3256:17)
    at /Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:15981:20
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3279:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23512:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23504:25)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:25521:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:25525:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:23975:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24271:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3500:88)
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
       ^
      Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
8 │ @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  stdin 8:9  root stylesheet
      in /Users/zarpio/code/p3backend/resources/sass/app.scss (line 8, column 9)
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/zarpio/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T11_47_10_138Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/zarpio/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T11_47_10_177Z-debug.log
```

Comment: obviously bootstrap 3 is different than bootstrap 4. You get pointed to the exact line you need to change.

Comment: I am not getting your point...

Comment: Why someone marks as a negative vote?

Comment: if you know how to fix it please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 and 4 have import paths. To import Bootstrap 3 using Webpack, use the following:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

This [thread](https://github.com/PatrickJS/starter/issues/696) has more information.